# Apple Distribution Certificates last for two years now?

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

According to the Apple developer documentation, each distribution certificate only lasts for one year:

> "A distribution certificate is valid for one year from date of issue."
>   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html

I just created a new distribution certificate today (in an Enterprise portal), and it seems to be valid for two years? Has Apple changed something recently?

Comment: Not according to the docs: http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/?lang=en#app43ad802c However I wouldn't be shocked if they changed it for enterprise distribution. 1 year is just a pain.

Comment: Same here... a two-year Enterprise Certificate, but aApples docs still say one year.